# Boolean error on codingbat

Tags: java

I'm doing a coding exercise on codingbat and this is what I am suppose to do:

Given 2 positive int values, return the larger value that is in the range 10..20 inclusive, or return 0 if neither is in that range.

max1020(11, 19) → 19
max1020(19, 11) → 19
max1020(11, 9) → 11
max1020(9, 21) → 0

my code:

```
public boolean IsInRange(int value)
{
  return value >= 10 && value <= 20;
}

public int max1020(int a, int b) {
  if (IsInRange(a) && IsInRange(b))
  return a > b ? a : b;
  else if (IsInRange(a))
  return a;
  else if (IsInRange(b))
  return b;

}
```

I don't understand why it doesn't work, it gives me this error:

```
Error:  public int max1020(int a, int b) {
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
This method must return a result of type int

Possible problem: the if-statement structure may theoretically 
allow a run to reach the end of the method without calling return.
Consider adding a last line in the method return some_value; 
so a value is always returned.
```

Answer (score 1):

I didn't have an else statement so the last input of a and b wouldn't have worked.
It should be this:

```
public boolean IsInRange(int value) {
    return value >= 10 && value <= 20;
}

public int max1020(int a, int b) {
  if (IsInRange(a) && IsInRange(b))
      return a > b ? a : b;
  else if (IsInRange(a))
      return a;
  else if (IsInRange(b))
      return b;
  else
      return 0;
}
```